# Getting error after uploading some product images in magento

Tags: image, magento

I'm getting a strange error in magento after uploading product images. I have this problem with only some images.

When i upload an image through backend product uploading section, its working perfectly and i can see the image when i ,mouse over it. But when i go to front end and browse the product detail page or the category page of that product, i'm getting a blank screen. I have this problem with only a few images. Images are in jpeg format.

Then when i reset magento default image as the base image and save the product, the problem solves. I cant figure what is the actual problem. Does any one have an idea. Kindly share it with me...

Thanks in Advance
Tibin Mathew

Answer (score 0):

A blank screen makes me think that you have and error somewhere in the code.
Can you check if you have display_errors = On and error_reporting = E_ALL in index.php?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); //uncomment this line to see errors
```

Or maybe you try to debug a large object like the layout block and the browser can't show it to you, also look for exceptions that may try to print very large data.